# Faster Alternative than Calculating Euclidian Distance to determine which Coordinate has Max Distance from a fixed coordinate (eg (0,0))

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

I am developing a program that needs me to determine which coordinate in a $2$-D figure has maximum distance from a fixed coordinate. Let me demonstrate:

$3$ points: $(1,3), (2,2), (5,0) $; 
Fixed point: $(0,0)$ ; 
Answer: $(5,0)$

I need to know **which point on the Cartesian Plane has a greater distance from the origin WITHOUT calculating $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ (Euclidian distance)** and preferably also without squaring and finding the square root.

Also, I need an approximation of this distance. Not necessary the literal distance (eg for $(3,4)$ I don't need $25$) but any transformed value in any domain which gives a measure of how further off the point is so I can use this value to compare to other maximum coordinates of other figures and quickly determine which coordinate will have maximum distance. 
A figure may have coordinates which have the same euclidean distance from the fixed point. (Eg $4,4$ and $-4,-4$).

Comment: For this problem you can simply omit the square root, as $\sqrt A\le\sqrt B \iff A\le B$ for any nonnegative numbers $A,B$. However, I'm afraid one cannot avoid squaring and adding the coordinates.

Comment: I was hoping a method would come up where i could take the absolute value of the coordinates and AVOID squaring somehow. Not possible? Values can be as large as 10^6

Comment: What system / program language are you working with?

Comment: @bholagabbar: You need _something_ nonlinear in order to get $\{a\mid a\text{ closer to }b\text{ than }c\text{ is}\}$ to have the proper circular shape -- linear computations would give you at best piecewise linear boundaries. And once you know you need something nonlinear, squaring is about the simplest imaginable option.

Comment: I'm working with JAVA. Because I have a large number of such calculations, I want to avoid BigInteger as it is slow. So I'm looking for an alternative

Comment: @bholagabbar: A Java `long` will handle the square of $10^6$ just fine.

Comment: Where and how that big data comes from? Cannot you already catch them into an ordered list at input?

Comment: Ok ill stick to the non-square root method and get back with a performance analysis

Comment: How about this? http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Fast_Approximate_Distance_Functions.shtml

Comment: These are *approximative* distances. It means, they might make mistakes about the real distance. However, maybe one of them will be appropriate for you if the shape of the domain where the points can came from is special.

Comment: I seem to have massively underestimated the power of modern computers. I precalculated all the squares of a numbers between 1 to 10^5 in under a second on JAVA. Problem solved :D